# Converting cells in a column in one worksheet as column headers in another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example:

Worksheet 1

```
 id category 
  1    dog
  2    cat 
  ....
```

Worksheet 2

```
name ,  dog , cat ....
```

However the first worksheet will grow so I can't use a paste special and when I link the cells =worksheet1!B2 and when I drag the fill handle downwards it gives the result I want. How would I achieve this because when I drag the fill handle sideways it doesn't give the desired affect

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my screenshot I've kept everything on one page so it is easier to see everything in one spot.
[image]

The code used is: `=INDEX($B:$B,COLUMNS($E$1:E1)+1)` or `=INDEX($B:$B,COLUMNS($D$1:E1))`

1. First the system is indexing column B.
2. Next we have a "counter" built that tells it to return the value in the "nth" column. In the first formula (and the one in the screenshot) I have a `+1` so it doesn't return the word "category"; as an alternative, in the second example, I just move the starting absolute reference one cell to the left.
3. Finally, after placing this in the desired cell (with appropriate cell references), simply drag to the right.

If you have any questions about this method or its implemntation, please feel free to ask.

Sample File: [HERE](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak6r9nlUd1ZOjPAYLwCyNj0ZPjt4BQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the formula as below:

```
=INDIRECT("worksheet1!B"&COLUMN(B1))
```

And then drag it to the right.

Indirect is usually something to avoid. In your example, if you move a cell or change the name of the first worksheet it will not work anymore.

Comment: so theres not a way without using indirect to change the fill handle copy down to a copy across

Comment: There are surely other way, but what disturbs you? And how big can be your file that you can't just copy paste transpose?

Comment: surely If I copy and paste transpose and I add more data to the original worksheet it wont update in the second one   Also my spreadsheet is very large and as indirect is quite volatile it would decrease the performance of the spreadsheet quite a bit

Comment: It is as volatile as you make it. If you want something that is less volatile make it static. If you want something responsive, accept that it is volatile.